# Which is the correct way to use `to_csv` after reading `json` from restapi ? How to get data in tabular format?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read data from : `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees` and trying to put it out in tabular format.

I am getting the output. But columns are not created from json file.
How can do this in right way?

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd    
import json    
df1 = pd.read_json('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')    
df1.to_csv('try.txt',sep='\t',index=False)
```

**Expected Output**:

```
employee_name   employee_salary         employee_age       profile_image
Tiger Nixon     320800                  61
```

(along with other rows)

Comment: Please format the code in your question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the data directly from the web, like you're doing, but you need to help pandas interpret your data with the `orient` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_json('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', orient='index')
```

Then there's a second step to focus on the data you want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.loc['data', 0])
```

Now you can write your csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different steps (note: the data is in [data] array of the JSON response):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

res = requests.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
data_str = res.content
data_dict = json.loads(data_str)

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict['data'])
data_df.to_csv('try.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse your json first.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
j = json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(j['data'])
```

output

```
id  employee_name   employee_salary employee_age    profile_image
0   1   Tiger Nixon 320800  61  
1   2   Garrett Winters 170750  63  
2   3   Ashton Cox  86000   66  
3   4   Cedric Kelly    433060  22  
4   5   Airi Satou  162700  33  
5   6   Brielle Williamson  372000  61  
6   7   Herrod Chandler 137500  59  
7   8   Rhona Davidson  327900  55  
8   9   Colleen Hurst   205500  39
```